# How Do I Know the Memory Used by Apps

Tags: monitoring, memory, ubuntu-12.04

Is it possible to know the memory used by any apps running on my linux server?

I'm using the following command to know how much memory used by php-fpm.

```
ps -ylC php5-fpm --sort:rss | awk '!/RSS/ { s+=$8 } END { printf "%s\n", "Total memory used by PHP-FPM child processes: "; printf "%dM\n", s/1024 }'
```

Given the command above, I want to know the memory used by all apps with an example output below:

PHP-FPM: 2.3gb
MySQL: 5gb
nginx: 200mb
dovecot: 100mb
memcached: 573mb

Update for MohyedeenN:

Thanks, but the output seems it's being duplicated as follows:

```
Total memory     used by config :
3M
Total memory     used by imap :
7M
Total memory     used by imap-login :
5M
Total memory     used by imap :
7M
Total memory     used by imap-login :
5M
Total memory     used by imap :
7M
Total memory     used by php5-fpm :
3671M
Total memory     used by php5-fpm :
3671M
Total memory     used by php5-fpm :
3671M
Total memory     used by php5-fpm :
3671M
Total memory     used by nginx :
54M
Total memory     used by nginx :
54M
Total memory     used by nginx :
54M
```

The above output is just a portion of the command you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please the following shellscript, tested on Centos 64bit.:

```
    for OUTPUT in $(ps -e |cut -d ":" -f 3 | cut -d " " -f 2 | sort -u)
      do
      ps -ylC $OUTPUT --sort:rss | awk '!/RSS/ { s+=$8 } END { printf "%s\n", "Total memory     used by '$OUTPUT' : "; printf "%dM\n", s/1024 }'
    done
```

Comment: Thank you. But the output seems duplicated. Please refer to my update above.

Comment: check the updated, just added sort -u at the end, to get only unique entries.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last follow up. Is it possible to sort this by the memory usage?